# "An error occurred while generating this PDF." in Commerce 2

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce2

Like the title says, I cannot output order PDFs in Commerce 2 and not sure how to debug this. Anyone else encountered the same issue?

Comment: That goes for control panel and front end btw.

Comment: To further clarify, I am able to output a PDF but it only contains the error message.

Comment: So you get an actual PDF file, but the contents of it say "An error occurred while generating this PDF"? Is that correct?  Are you using the stock order template for PDFs?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there was a broken include in the order template. Sorted now though thanks.

Comment: I'm currently having the same issue.  Would you care to share how you fixed it?

Comment: Hi Eric. Decided not to use order PDFs for now, as they're not necessary for this first iteration of the store.